# Override CSS for a:link by class

Tags: html, css

In the existing CSS file, we have:

```
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #0486d9;
}

a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #0486d9;
}
```

Which is fine, but I don't want that style in all cases.  For example, for this link, I want it always white and underlined:

```
<a id="someId" class="GridviewSort" href="...">Date</a>
```

I thought this would do it:

```
.GridviewSort a:link {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: white;
}

.GridviewSort a:visited {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: white;
}
```

But it's not. The original style remains. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

Thanks, stybl.  For some reason the original blue is still being dominant. But the Underline is working! Here's what's happening:

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

Ok, further up in the same style sheet is this:

```
a {
    color: #0486d9 !important;
}
```

Which is still forcing the link to be blue.  I don't want to change or remove this line because of the impact it might have elsewhere in the site.  Is there a way to override this one too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.GridviewSort a:visited` targets `<a>` tags that are *children of* elements with the `GridviewSort` class. What you want is to target `<a>` tags that have that class.

This should work:

```
a.GridviewSort:link {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: white;
}

a.GridviewSort:visited {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: white;
}
```

**Note:** if you intend to have the same exact style for both clicked and unclicked links, you can shorten it like so:

```
a.GridviewSort:link,
a.GridviewSort:visited {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: ah!  I think I see the problem. There is another style sheet in play here.

Comment: or, same style sheet, but another line

Comment: I'm afraid I can't repro. See if you can get the same thing to happen in a snippet.